# NextAuth Callback function in Google SignIn

Tags: async-await, next.js, callback, google-signin, next-auth

I want to show notification after **Google SignIn** is done using **signIn()** function in **NextAuth.js**

**googleSignInHandler** is a function which is called when Google icon is clicked. In **NextAuth.js**, **signIn** is a function provided by **next-auth/react**. After successful login I want to show notification of successful login.
Following is the **googleSignInHandler** function

```js
    const googleSignInHandler = async () => {
        await signIn('google', { callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000" })

        toast.success('Signed In Successfully!')
    }
```

In `signIn('google', { callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000"  })`, after successful login, page is redirected to **callbackUrl**.

`toast.success('Signed In Successfully!')` displays notification of successful sign in.

I want to display notification when the sign in is done. But, as soon as **googleSignInHandler** is called, `toast.success('Signed In Successfully!')` gets executed immediately before signing in.

First of all, signing in should be done, then after redirection the notification should be showed. For this purpose, I think, there is need of callback function. Using **await** before signIn function does not help. I read the documentation but I didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it the following way as a workaround:

```
const googleSignInHandler = async () => {
        await signIn('google')
    }
```

This will redirect me to the same login page where it started ( I am assuming you are using a custom Login page and not the default one as I am not sure how redirect would work with that, but you may try)

Now I use the following **useEffect** on my Login page:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      toast.success("You have successfully logged in!")
      setTimeout(()=>{
        router.push("/")
      }, 800)
    }
    
  }, [session])
```

This will redirect me to the Homepage (or whatever page you want) after a set interval and will also display the Toast success message.

You may skip `setTimeout` and use `router.push` directly, I just used it for a slightly better user experience

Make sure you are using the **useSession** React Hook to import the session from nextAuth